# Function specific expansion series

Tags: python, function, numpy

I would like to achieve a specific expansion series but I don't know how I can do that.
My aim is to be able to specify the order of my series in order to avoid to write a great number of functions for each order:

[image]

I tried that:

```
import numpy as np

order = 3

def expan(order) :
    n = 0
    expan = 0
    add = (Kappa + n/2. + (-1)**n)*np.cos(n*theta/2.) - n/2.*np.cos((n-4)*theta/2.)
    for i in order:
        expan += add        
        power += 1
return expan
```

Comment: Probably people trying to get the imitation crab hat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize things with numpy and do something like:

```
def expand(order, kappa, theta):
    n = np.arange(order)
    return np.sum((kappa + n/2 + (-1)**n)*np.cos(n*theta/2) -
                  n/2*np.cos((n-4)*theta/2))
```

Comment: but it doesn t work if i want to do a minizimation which is my aim... :/

Comment: You will have to explain in more detail what "doing a minimization" means, and how it "doesn't work" to get help. A new question is probably the way to go.